# Cannot get AppInsights working under Spring Boot

Tags: azure, spring-boot, azure-application-insights

I followed the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-java-get-started, but still without success.

- I have applicationinsights-web dependency in place via maven
- I added `ApplicationInsights.xml` to main/resources with hardcoded instrumentation key and even with `<SDKLogger />` inside
- I added the scan path: `@ComponentScan({...., "com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.spring"})`

Results:

- I see no logs about looking up the configuration file, even if I make the syntax error in in or remove it completely
- in debug I see that `RequestNameHandlerInterceptorAdapter` is instantiated via `com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.spring.internal.InterceptorRegistry`, and during calls the `preHandle` method is called, but calls to `ThreadContext.getRequestTelemetryContext()` returns always null and nothing more happens

It looks like it is something obvious, but no idea what. What part/classes are responsible for loading the configuration file?

Comment: async server implementation?

Comment: @yonisha what do you mean?

Comment: In a synchronous server implementation, the entire request is processed by the same thread. In an async server implementation - the request MAY be processed be several threads.

AI Java SDK does not support async servlet implementation, which can explain the null when calling getRequestTelemetryContext.

You can read more here on sync vs. async - http://www.javatpoint.com/understanding-synchronous-vs-asynchronous

Comment: Server-side implementation is synchronous, the use case is very simple - it is about handling single REST request. For me more disturbing is lack of any logs related to loading the configuration file - apparently the whole app insight thing does not initialize correctly, but have no idea why and what to check as a next step...

Comment: Do you see any logs of the SDK? Can you share your configuration file? also, Windows / Linux?

Comment: I do local tests on Windows. I have set the logs level to debug globally and have not found any from sdk. The config file is copy-pasted from docs. Cannot post it since its weekend wright now:-)

Comment: 1) SDK logs are printed to console. 2) it seems like the SDK is not being bootstrap. Have you added the required http filter configuration? This one makes all the magic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-java-get-started#4-add-an-http-filter

Comment: You made me rethink docs again, @yonisha. Id did not put that filter, I thought that the SpringMVC-related section overrides it:) I configured it  and now I can see the results. I will share in a moment code example how to do this in Spring Boot. Thanks for your support

Answer (score 5):

I was a little bit confused with documentation. As mentioned by yonisha, the filter does the whole magic. The following configuration class takes care of creating and adding the filter in Spring Boot application.

```
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.internal.WebRequestTrackingFilter;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.servlet.Filter;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.spring")
public class ApplicationInsightsConfiguration {

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean someFilterRegistration() {

    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.setFilter(appInsightsWebRequestTrackingFilter());
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    registration.setName("webRequestTrackingFilter");
    registration.setOrder(1);
    return registration;
}


@Bean(name = "appInsightsWebRequestTrackingFilter")
public Filter appInsightsWebRequestTrackingFilter() {
    return new WebRequestTrackingFilter();
}
```

Important: It will work nicely if you set the `server.context-path` property to some value. If not, AI initialization will fail with error

```
AI: ERROR 03-04-2017 14:11, 20: WebApp name is not found, unable to register WebApp
```

In order to keep servlet-context empty, I had to implement wrappers for the filter and 2 other classes to override it, but it was a very dirty fix... Would be great, if the name could be passed as a parameter to the filter, but that is not yet possible (https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Java/issues/359)

Comment: Is there a way to enable AI capture response payloads too in Spring Boot application?

Answer (score 1):

In spring boot , We need to configure `WebRequestTrackingFilter` by extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and overriding  `configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity)`

```
    @Bean
    public WebRequestTrackingFilter applicationInsightsFilterBean() throws Exception {
        WebRequestTrackingFilter webRequestTrackingFilter = new WebRequestTrackingFilter();
        return webRequestTrackingFilter;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        //other stuff...
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(applicationInsightsFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

you need to have below configuration also ..

- applicationinsights-web dependency in place via maven
- added ApplicationInsights.xml to main/resources

Answer (score 1):

Here is newer guide for Spring Boot Application Insights integration that worked well for me just now:

https://github.com/AzureCAT-GSI/DevCamp/tree/master/HOL/java/06-appinsights

The idea is basically what Tomasz has above with some minor differences.

```
package devCamp.WebApp.configurations;

import javax.servlet.Filter;

import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.TelemetryConfiguration;
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.internal.WebRequestTrackingFilter;


@Configuration
public class AppInsightsConfig {

    @Bean
    public String telemetryConfig() {
        String telemetryKey = System.getenv("APPLICATION_INSIGHTS_IKEY");
        if (telemetryKey != null) {
            TelemetryConfiguration.getActive().setInstrumentationKey(telemetryKey);
        }
        return telemetryKey;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean aiFilterRegistration() {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setFilter(new WebRequestTrackingFilter());
        registration.addUrlPatterns("/**");
        registration.setOrder(1);
        return registration;
    } 

    @Bean(name = "WebRequestTrackingFilter")
    public Filter WebRequestTrackingFilter() {
        return new WebRequestTrackingFilter();
    }   
}
```

The guide at the link above has a full set of instructions and includes client side js and a java log appender example as well. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The above all method works! However you can try the whole new seamless experience using Application Insights SpringBoot Starter.

https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Java/blob/master/azure-application-insights-spring-boot-starter/README.md

This is currently in BETA

Comment: Thanks, will check

Comment: Links is broken