# TelemetryConfiguration is not public in com.microsoft.applicationinsights after updating version to 3.4.9

Tags: java, spring, azure-application-insights

Maven suggests to update com.microsoft.azure:applicationinsights-web to 3.4.9 version, previously I was using 2.6.2. After updating I get errors:
`java: com.microsoft.applicationinsights.TelemetryConfiguration is not public in com.microsoft.applicationinsights; cannot be accessed from outside package`
and
`java: cannot find symbol symbol:   class WebRequestTrackingFilter location: package com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.internal`

If I update to the latest 2.x application insights version, everything works fine. But not with 3.x version. I'm using Spring boot 2.7.13.
Could you please advise what steps should I take to resolve this issue?

Code that I'm using is similar to code below ([Cannot get AppInsights working under Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064476/cannot-get-appinsights-working-under-spring-boot))

```
@Configuration
public class AppInsightsConfig {

    @Bean
    public String telemetryConfig() {
        String telemetryKey = System.getenv("APPLICATION_INSIGHTS_IKEY");
        if (telemetryKey != null) {
            TelemetryConfiguration.getActive().setInstrumentationKey(telemetryKey);
        }
        return telemetryKey;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean aiFilterRegistration() {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setFilter(new WebRequestTrackingFilter());
        registration.addUrlPatterns("/**");
        registration.setOrder(1);
        return registration;
    } 

    @Bean(name = "WebRequestTrackingFilter")
    public Filter WebRequestTrackingFilter() {
        return new WebRequestTrackingFilter();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Did you get it working by any chance? I face a similar issue like this when I am trying to upgrade the library `aplicationinsifghts.core` from 2.x to 3.x and I am unable to fix it since nowhere in Microsoft's documentation I see an alternative way to achieve the same.

Comment: @Abhi, I used `applicationinsights-web` dependency before and replaced it with `applicationinsights-runtime-attach`. I followed this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-spring-boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens due to incompatibility between the versions of the dependencies and spring boot.

- `applicationinsights-web` version 3.4.9 is not compatible with `Spring Boot 2.7.13`.
- `applicationinsights-web` **2.x.x** version is compatible with `spring-boot` 2.x.x.

**Check if below steps help to fix your issue:**

- If you are upgrading application insights web version, you need to upgrade ***spring boot*** version to be compatible with the upgraded ***application insights-web*** version.
- And also, upgrade `application-insights-core` package to its *latest version* to be compatible with your `application-insights-web` version.

```java
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>applicationinsights-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.15</version>
</dependency>
```

- Import `com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.internal.WebRequestTrackingFilter` and `com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.internal.WebRequestTrackingFilter` class in your code.

```java
package  com.example.demo;

import  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import  org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import  org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import  org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import  com.microsoft.applicationinsights.TelemetryConfiguration;
import  com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.internal.WebRequestTrackingFilter;
```

- Instead, you can also use `applicationinsights-runtime-attach` [dependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-spring-boot#enabling-programmatically) in your pom.xml to configure Application Insights.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>applicationinsights-runtime-attach</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.15</version>
</dependency>
```

**References:**

[Upgrading from 2.x - Azure Monitor Application Insights Java - Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-standalone-upgrade-from-2x)

Comment: Thank you, I used `applicationinsights-runtime-attach`.